# Delete file which cannot delete because is used by another process

Tags: c#, delete-file

I know you are going to tell me that this question is stupid but I really cannot find a solution to delete my file.

In fact, I open a connection to an .add file (same style as SQL in a way) but afterwards I cannot delete it because it is used by another process which is the process of my application.

While doing some research on the internet I was able to find the solution to kill the process however if I do this it stops my application. Then I also found the GC collect but it doesn't work : /

There is my code :

```
        try
        {
            string idClient = "parfilux";
            string tableName = "ACT,ACF";
            string dataSourceDBF = "C:/winbooks/data/parfilux";
            string path = dataSourceDBF ;
            string pathTemp = dataSourceDBF + "/CopyTempWebService/";

            if (!Directory.Exists(pathTemp)) Directory.CreateDirectory(pathTemp);


            string addFile = path + "/" + idClient + ".add";
            File.Copy(addFile, pathTemp + idClient.ToUpper() + ".add");
            File.Copy(addFile.Replace(".add", ".ai"), pathTemp + "/" + idClient.ToUpper() + ".ai");
            File.Copy(addFile.Replace(".add", ".am"), pathTemp + "/" + idClient.ToUpper() + ".am");

            tableName = tableName.Replace(" ", "");
            string[] tables = tableName.Split(',');

            string pathTable = null;
            foreach (string tab in tables)
            {
                pathTable = path + "/" + idClient.ToUpper() + "_" + tab.ToUpper() + ".dbf";
                File.Copy(pathTable, pathTemp + idClient.ToUpper() + "_" + tab.ToUpper() + ".dbf");
                File.Copy(pathTable.Replace(".dbf", ".cdx"), pathTemp + idClient.ToUpper() + "_" + tab.ToUpper() + ".cdx");
            }

            AdsConnection dbfCo;
            //dbfCo.Close();
            dbfCo = new AdsConnection(@"data Source=" + dataSourceDBF + "/CopyTempWebService/" + idClient + ".add;User ID=admin;Password=;ServerType=Local;ReadOnly=true;pooling=true;TrimTrailingSpaces=true;ShowDeleted=TRUE;TableType=CDX;LockMode=COMPATIBLE");

            dbfCo.Open();

            //QueryDataDBF(tableName, idClient, false);
            dbfCo.Close();
            dbfCo.Dispose();


            //Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            //Console.WriteLine(process.MainModule);
            //process.Kill();
            //foreach(Process pro in process)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(pro);
            //    if(pro.ProcessName == pathTemp + idClient.ToUpper() + ".add")
            //    {
            //        pro.Kill();
            //    }
            //}
            
            //System.GC.Collect();
            //System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            //File.Delete(pathTemp + idClient.ToUpper() + ".add");

           Directory.Delete(dataSourceDBF + "/CopyTempWebService", true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

I open a connection to my .add with the Advantage Data Provider library.

Do you have any idea to fix this problem ? thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Use [using blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to create a scope where your file objects are created. After leaving that scope, everything will be disposed correctly without the need to call `Dispose` manually on all streams/file handlers.

Comment: Thank for your answer ! But I tried to put a using on my connection (AdsConnection) but it still does not work, should it be put on the block which copies my files? If so could you show me an example because I really don't see how to implement this using with File.Copy